# MVC3 with Tabs and page Layouts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout

I am developing an MVC3 web application and I need to create a layout similar to SalesForce's tab driven layout.
I tried creating a partial view to render my sidebar navigation within my tab content area. CSS positioning does not work since I need to remain within my tab's content area.
How should I properly render my interior navigation menu and my content and remain within the tabbed content area. I tried posting a screenshot of salesforce but new users of this site cannot load images.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    "#tabs-1">Project
    #tabs-2">Metrics
     href="#tabs-3">Task
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">   
             @Html.Partial("_SideBar")

</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Content for TAB2</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Content for TAB3.</p>
</div>
```

---

Well, the problem I have is that I am trying to use JqueryUI TAB widget with my _Layout page.  I am trying to embed a 2 column layout that has a sidebar navigation in the first column and content in the second column. This must be displayed within the walls of the TAB's view areas. So, if I clicked TAB1 you can see navigation that is in column 1 and the content that is in column 2. If I then click TAB 2, I would like to still have navigation on the left and content on the right but they would have different data in them. The biggest issue is how do I make sure that these columns within the TAB's view area remain in the TAB's view area and not be rendered out side the TAB completely.. I hope this was clear. Please let me know if I need to provide further info. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misled by the JQuery Tab component. The float property was causing the tab not to expand making it look like nothing was remaning inside the div tag. Simply remove float property from outer tag

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to fully get what you want here, but are you just wanting to use regions for your layout? For instance

```
<div id="tabs-2">
     @RenderSection("Tab2Content", required: false)
</div>
```

and in your views:

```
@section Tab2Content{
content here
}
```

Comment: I was misled by the JQuery Tab component. The float property was causing the tab  not to expand making it look like nothing was remaning inside the div tag. Simply remove float property from outer tag